# PHP shell_exec() doesn't allow less-than "<" character or "<()" command to be used?

Tags: php, shell-exec, php-7.3

I need to run this exact shell command from PHP shell_exec():

```
/usr/bin/paste -d'|' <(echo $(id)) <(echo $(pwd))
```

From a VPS shell (Debian) it works perfectly. However, from shell_exec() it doesn't work:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/paste -d'|' <(echo $(id)) <(echo $(pwd)) 2>&1";

$output = shell_exec($command);

print_r($output);
```

It doesn't output anything, the output is just blank/empty.

I am using PHP 7.3 with safe_mode = On and open_basedir, shell_exec() is enabled.

How can I run that command with shell_exec()?

I think the less-than "<" char or "<()" create problems?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps escapeshellcmd would help ?

```
$command = "/usr/bin/paste -d'|' <(echo $(id)) <(echo $(pwd)) 2>&1";

$escaped_command = escapeshellcmd($command);

$output = shell_exec($escaped_command);

print_r($output);
```

good luck.